# Website downloads php file instead of loading page NGINX

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I setup a website under a subfolder on a Nginx server: https://pixlgraphx.com/oldwebsite/.

Website loads perfectly the homepage. Until I tried to load other pages they download a php file instead.

My Nginx config file is here:

```
location /oldwebsite{
 try_files $uri $uri/ /oldwebsite/index.php$args /oldwebsite/index.php?q=$uri$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/pixlgraphx.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS "on";
fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https";
 client_max_body_size 128M;
}
```

[Nginx Config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nb7H.png)

[Nginx Config File 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64MS4.png)

[Nginx Config File 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyK9w.png)

Comment: You have `/oldwebsite/index.php` **twice** in the `try_files` statement. It needs to be the last parameter.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand. Do you mean to put it at last? i'm a junior at this, thanks

Comment: You don’t want both. Remove one.

Comment: OMG it worked! I have other sites under subfolders as well and they worked with the same configuration pretty well. I wonder why this one gave me this headache

Comment: hey if you add your comment as a answer i will take it as solve. Put it as answer